# error while run roscore on armel ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ros, rospkg, roscore, rosversion, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have installed ros groovy from source on armel ubuntu 12.04.At first,roscore can run successfully.But now,when I run roscore I got the following  message:

```
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated                                                                      
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.                                                                              
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt                                                                                                                 
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.                                                                                         
2;roscore                                                                                                                                 
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [rosversion]: command [rosversion roslaunch] returned with code [1].                   
                                                                                                                                          
Param xml is <param command="rosversion roslaunch" name="rosversion"/>
```

So I deleted the log through:`$ rosclean purge`
Than refer to the website http://answers.ros.org/question/44996/cannot-run-roscore-due-to-error-in-rosversion/
remove the old rospkg:

```
 $ sudo pip uninstall rospkg
```

than install the latest version.`$sudo pip install -U rospkg`
When I run roscore there is always  the same message.
please help me. Thank you very  much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199142/error-while-run-roscore-on-armel-ubuntu-12.04/) by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2014-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This usually happens when the rosversion can't be found, or when the rosversion command can't find your ROS installation.

I would check that you've sourced the setup.bash for your ROS installation.

You can also debug a bit more by running the command in question:

```
rosversion roslaunch
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-12-10**:
Now,the roscore can run normally.It is really due to setup.bash. I add many ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the setup.bash.when I deleted  them the roscore can run successfully.Can not add too many ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the setup.bash?

**Comment by [Alice63](https://answers.ros.org/users/19628/alice63/) on 2014-12-10**:
If i add  many ROS_PACKAGE_PATH,it will show: `$rosversion roslaunch

```
cannot locate [roslaunch]`
```

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-10**:
I've never seen an instance where a user's ROS_PACKAGE_PATH was too large. What's more likely is that you're overwriting your original ROS_PACKAGE_PATH instead of appending to it, and losing the part of the path which points to the core packages.